# show html code in html grid

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
newcontent += 
"<tr id=\"" + a[i][0] + "\">
  <td class=\"row\">" + a[i][0] + "</td>
  <td>" + a[i][4] + "</td>
  <td>" + a[i][3] + "</td>
  <td>" + a[i][1] + "</td>
  <td class=\"edit\">
    <img class=\"editrow\" name=\"" + a[i][2] + "\" src=\"../images/1321797859_edit.png\" />
    <img class=\"deleterow\" name=\"" + a[i][2] + "\" src=\"../images/1321787179_edit-delete.png\" />
    <a href=\"../interface/qb-topic.aspx?c=" + qsParm[key] + "&id=" + a[i][2] + "\">
      <img class=\"showrow\"  src=\"../images/1325079018_application_view_detail.png\" />
    </a>";
```

I get value from ajax function in to a[i][1].this value is html code , like some text that wrote with ckeditor.but this not display(sorry about my bad languge).

```
[{"rownum":"1","Id_questions":"6","Text_questions":"
```

تست3

","Level":"آسان","topic":"درخت"},{"rownum":"2","Id_questions":"5","Text_questions":"
تست3

","Level":"سخت","topic":"تقسیم و غلبه"},{"rownum":"3","Id_questions":"3","Text_questions":"تست","Level":"سخت","topic":"درخت"},{"rownum":"4","Id_questions":"2","Text_questions":"خوبی؟","Level":"متوسط","topic":"تقسیم و غلبه"},{"rownum":"5","Id_questions":"1","Text_questions":"نام شما چیست؟","Level":"آسان","topic":"تقسیم و غلبه"}]

it's json string that I get it from db.
and in 4 lines first has html code. " تست3 " is in a

tag.it's my problem and I can't fixed it.

Comment: there's a difference between html code and string; is `a[i][0]` a string?

Comment: I can see only the place where you assign string to a variable named `newcontent`. Where is place where you try to actually display contents of it?

Comment: $("#grid").append(newcontent);  grid is a div

Comment: @PetrMarek There are no difference from HTML code and string because HTML code is string anyways. Problem might be that he tries to display string with HTML contents using `.text()` not `.html()` as supposed.

Comment: @8611670474 Are you sure that `$('#grid')` exists at the time you try to append new values to it? Double-check by `console.log()` function.

Comment: I'm sure , when I edit a[i][1] in database and clear html tag , display that.

Comment: Check that variable named `a` and `i` exists. Check that `a[i][0]` exists! Do debug, mate.

Comment: you never close your last td and tr

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 2d array method but your answer is in struct.
if you want't to get that then write like this....

```
newcontent += 
"<tr id=\"" + a[i]["rownum"] + "\">
  <td class=\"row\">" + a[i]["rownum"] + "</td>
  <td>" + a[i]["Text_questions"] + "</td>
  <td>" + a[i]["Text_questions"] + "</td>
  <td>" + a[i]["Id_questions"] + "</td>
  <td class=\"edit\">
    <img class=\"editrow\" name=\"" + a[i]["Text_questions"] + "\" src=\"../images/1321797859_edit.png\" />
    <img class=\"deleterow\" name=\"" + a[i]["Text_questions"] + "\" src=\"../images/1321787179_edit-delete.png\" />
    <a href=\"../interface/qb-topic.aspx?c=" + qsParm[key] + "&id=" + a[i]["Text_questions"] + "\">
      <img class=\"showrow\"  src=\"../images/1325079018_application_view_detail.png\" />
    </a>";
```